# Terminating class template recursion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I initially had the following recursive variadic template code

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// end of recursion
void apply(std::function<void()> f, int)
{
    f();
}

// base recursive 
template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
void apply(std::function<void(Head, Tail...)> f, int i)
{
    auto g = [=](Tail&& ...args)
    {
        f(i, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
    };

    apply(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, ++i);
}

void foo(int a, int b, double c, int d)
{
    std::cout << a << b << c << d << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::function<void(int, int, double, int)>(foo);
    apply(f, 0);
}
```

it works fine, but I had to add a case for Head=double, so I ended up using partially specializing structs

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// base recursive case
template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>
struct Apply {
    static void apply(std::function<void(Head, Tail...)> f, int i)
    {
        auto g = [=](Tail&& ...args)
        {
            f(i, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
        };

        Apply<Tail...>::apply(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, ++i);
    }
};

// specialization case for double
template <typename ...Tail>
struct Apply<double, Tail...> {
    static void apply(std::function<void(double, Tail...)> f, int i)
    {
        auto g = [=](Tail&& ...args)
        {
            f(777.0, std::forward<Tail>(args)...);
        };

        Apply<Tail...>::apply(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, ++i);
    }
};

// end of recursion
template <>
struct Apply {
    static void apply(std::function<void()> f, int)
    {
        f();
    }
};

void foo(int a, int b, double c, int d)
{
    std::cout << a << b << c << d << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::function<void(int, int, double, int)>(foo);
    Apply<int, int, double, int>::apply(f, 0);
}
```

but I don't seem to be able to came up with the correct "end of recursion" version of the struct, when it's called as `Apply<Tail...>::apply(std::function<void(Tail...)>{g}, ++i);`, where `Tail...` is empty.

The way the struct is declared -- `template <typename Head, typename ...Tail>` -- it requires at lease one type to be there, so it can't be empty, and I can't end the recursion because of that. But I also can't lift that requirement, because I need a way to reference all types but the first one (i.e. `Tail...`) in `apply` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a primary template which allows the empty specialization.

```
template <typename ...Types>
struct Apply;
```

Now provide the two partial specializations:

```
template <typename ... Tail>
struct Apply<double, Tail...>
{
...
};

template <typename Head, typename ... Tail, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<Head, double>::value>>
struct Apply<Head, Tail...>
{
...
};
```

And, finally, the empty specialization:

```
template <>
struct Apply<>
{
...
};
```

Comment: That was... simple. Sorry, I'm still getting over templates! Also, do we really need to check that Head is not double? `typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<Head, double>::value>` What exactly it accomplishes? To me it looks redundant, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: In this case, that check is likely redundant - I need to double-check the partial ordering rules for partial specializations. Hopefully, one of the experts here will see this comment and let you know for sure :) But the `enable_if...` phrase helps you in other situations. Say you want to specify one partial specialization for `Head` being an intergral type and another for `Head` being a floating-point type. You will need to use something like `enable_if...` to ensure that only one of those partial specializations match.